# Number of random values that are recorded as being greater than all previous values

Tags: probability

Basically, given a continuous distribution with a density function f, record all numbers that are larger than all previous values.  (if the sequence 3, 2, 4, 3.5, 5 is generated, 3,4, and 5 are the recorded values).

I need to find the expected number of recorded values when 100 such values are generated.

My original thinking was that given a continious distribution from -infinity to infinity, there is a 50% chance that the next value will be larger than the current largest value, meaning that given the first value generated is automatically recorded, the remaining 99 values have a 50% chance to be larger, which would imply an estimated recorded value of 49.5 (rounded to 50) plus the first value for a grand total of 51 values.

After briefly discussing with my professor, this is apparently an incorrect way to go about the problem, and I am curious how I should go about solving this instead?  I assume there is some sort of diminishing returns on the chance that the number is largest, but as it is a continuous set and not a finite set, I don't follow why that would be the case.

Comment: Under "My original thinking" if you generate $1,3,2$ the $2$ is larger than the $1$, but not the largest so far.  It is a reasonable approach for the fraction larger than the first, but not largest so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_i=1$ if at the $i$-th trial we get something bigger than all the previous ones, and $X_i=0$ otherwise.

Then the number of "biggests so far" is $X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_{100}$.

Now use the linearity of expectation to calculate $E(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_{100})$.

To calculate $E(X_i)$, note that this is $\Pr(X_i=1)$.

Since the distribution is continuous, with probability $1$ al results are different. What is the probability that the $i$-th result is bigger than all the previous ones? To put it another way: look at the numbers obtained on trials $1$ to $i$. What is the probability the biggest among these occurs at the end?

This is where your intuition about "diminishing returns" gets an explicit number attached to it.

**Added:** Let $n=100$. If $W$ is the number of values that we write down, then 
$$W=E_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n,$$
and therefore
$$E(W)=E(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n)=E(X_1)+E(X_2)+\cdots+E(X_n).$$
Among the $i$ values obtained in the first $i$ trials, the largest is equally likely to be in any of the $i$ places, so the probability it is at $i$ is $\frac{1}{i}$.

Thus $E(X_i)=(1)\frac{1}{i}+(0)\frac{i-1}{i}=\frac{1}{i}$. It follows that
$$E(W)=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots +\frac{1}{n}.$$
This number is the $n$-th **harmonic number** $H_n$.

Comment: Assuming I am following correctly, the chance that the largest value at the end will be 1/i trials, as there are i-1 other trials to compare it against, would this then imply that the solution should be the sum of the probabilities at each trial, i, ending with the final value having a probability of  1/100 that it will be recorded?

Comment: Yes, $X_i$ is $1$ with probability $\frac{1}{i}$, so our expectation is $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{100}$. For general $n$, it is $1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}$, which is roughly $\ln n$. For details about very precise estimates of this sum, look up *harmonic numbers* $H_n$.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, I guess I am unsure how to get an expected value from that sum though, as I am used to finding an E(X) from a [number of samples] * [overall probability] which has always been under 1, yet the sum of this is ~5.18.

Comment: I will change my answer to be more explicit. The answer is not very far from $ln 100$, I can't understand how you got a negative number from adding up $1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{100}$. By the way, I think that answer would be considered enough.

Comment: Sorry, I was using a tilde as an approximation symbol, I should have used $ \approx $ instead, but the formatting here is still a bit new to me.  But are you saying that the total number of recorded values should just be the 

$$
\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=0}^{100} 1/i
$$

Which equals 5.1873

Comment: Yes, that is a good approximation to the expectation. To a couple more places, $5.187377$ I think. Note that getting the expectation by finding the **distribution** of the random variable I called $W$, and then using the ordinary formula for expectation, would be a nightmare.

Comment: I believe the $X_i$ *are* independent, since $X_i = \mathbf 1_{A_i}$ where $A_i = \{i\text{th trial is a new max}\}$ and the $A_i$ are known to be mutually independent events. (Lemma 1 of A. Renyi (1962), [Théorie des éléments saillants d'une suite d'observations](http://archive.numdam.org/article/ASCFM_1962__8_2_7_0.pdf),  *Annales scientifiques de l'Université de Clermont. Mathématiques* 8.2.)

Comment: @cardinal: I will check, probably by tomorrow, and delete the remark if the set $\{X_1,X_2,\dots, X_n\}$ is independent.